# How to get certain outputs out of a dict block

Tags: python

My RPG-related issues have transmogrified. I have a dict block of weapons, defined with (I believe) their value and damage. How do I generate a certain weapon as output, say, for a merchant to have for sale?

Here's the weapon class:

```
class weapon(object):
  def __init__(name, loot_worth, damage):
    Character.__init__(self)
    self.damage = Damage
  def Damage(weapon):
    self.damage = Damage
```

Segment of dict block:

```
weapon_dict = {"None"             : [0, 0],
               "Imaginary Sword"  : [0, 0],
               "Twig"             : [0, 1]
              }
```

The merchHasWeapon function block:

```
def merchHasWeapon(self):
    if self.merchstate == 'buy':
      return random.choice(weapon_dict.keys())
```

And the merch function:

```
def merch(self):
  self.merchstate == 'buy'
  self.merchstim = randint (0, 10)
  self.merchammo = randint (0, 50)
  if randint(0, 1):
    temp_wpn = self.merchHasWeapon()
    temo_armr = self.merchHasArmor()
    print("Merch weapon: {} , Stats: {}".format(temp_wpn,weapon_dict[temp_wpn]))
    print("Merch armor: {} , Stats: {}".format(temo_armr,armor_dict[temo_armr]))
  print "%s goes to the Merchants' Clearing. For help with merchants, type mh." % self.name
  print "Merchant's items:\n~Potions:%d\n~Arrows:%d\n" % (self.merchstim, self.merchammo)
```

The error message that prints if the "def merchHasWeapon" block comes before the "def merch" block is "zero length field name in format." If it comes after, it says "global name merch isn't defined." Could someone help me remedy this error?

Comment: Could you please fix the indentation levels in your code :). Especially the last piece of code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
if randint(0, 1):
    print("Merch weapon: {} , Stats: {}".format(merch_weapon,weapon_dict[merch_weapon]))
    print("Merch armor: {} , Stats: {}".format(merch_armor, armor_dict[merch_armor]))
```

Firstly, `merch_weapon` is a function, so you actually have to call it by doing `self.merch_weapon()`. Next, your `merch_weapon` function should return something so you can use it when accessing the dictionary:

```
def merch_weapon(self):
    if self.merchstate == 'buy':
      return random.choice(weapon_dict.keys()) # list() isn't needed here
```

Now, when you go to print your weapon and armour stats, don't forget the parentheses:

```
if randint(0, 1):
    temp_wpn = merch_weapon()
    temo_armr = merch_armor()
    print("Merch weapon: {} , Stats: {}".format(temp_wpn, weapon_dict[temp_wpn]))
    print("Merch armor: {} , Stats: {}".format(temo_armr, armor_dict[temo_armr]))
```

Comment: @Velcrode I think that's what I've done. See how I call the function in my code? `merch_weapon()`

Comment: @Velcrode Does `merchstate == 'buy'`?

Comment: @Velcrode I have edited my answer (The code at the end). Try now

Comment: It still says the 'str' object isn't callable... Hm.

Comment: @Velcrode Have you accidentally named a variable `merch_weapon` too?

Comment: I have the global name "merch_weapon = random.choice(weapon_dict.keys())" and the same for merch_armor.

Comment: @Velcrode global? Hmm... In your `merch_weapon` function, did you change it to what I did? (put a return statement)

Comment: Ya. Should I define merch_weapon after the merch function?

Comment: @Velcrode Rename the `merch_weapon = random.choice(weapon_dict.keys())` something else. Don't get it mixed up wwith the function

Comment: Shouldn't I associate merch_weapon with something in the global frame if I'm going to use it in the merch_weapon/merch functions?

Comment: @Velcrode Yes, but don't mix up your variable names! You can't just name one thing `merch_weapon` then name another thing the same name! Python won't know the difference.

Comment: If I change the name of that definition, it says "the global name merch_weapon isn't defined"

Comment: @Velcrode Then change `merch_weapon` in my code to the name of the new function.

Comment: I changed the function to merchHasWeapon, but the 'str is not callable' error remains. Perhaps it's a problem with "temp_wpn = merch_weapon()"?

Comment: @Velcrode Yes, lmao. Change `merch_weapon` to `merchHasWeapon`.

Comment: Now it says the global name "merchHasWeapon" is not defined. =(

Comment: @Velcrode Oh, try `self.merchHasWeapon`

Comment: Heh, now it says 'merch' isn't defined (it is...?).

Comment: @Velcrode Have a good, hard look at your code. Don't forget your `self`s before your variable names if you created them in a class. If you rename something, make sure to fix the names where it is called. Error messages can help you

Comment: Everything seems to be correct, it comes down to needing to create a global definition for a function in order to call that function in another function in the Player class. Right?

Comment: @Velcrode Correct. But if you have two functions in a class, you can call each other by doing `self.func()`

Comment: I see. So now I define a merch globally?

Comment: @Velcrode The variable? Make it `self.merch = 5` or whatever :p

Comment: Interesting, depending on whether I put the "def merchHasWeapon()" function (before or after), I get, respectively, a "zero length field name in format" or a "global name merch not defined" error.

Comment: "global name self is not defined!"

Comment: @Velcrode Oh, I thought you were doing all of this in a class

Comment: It's all in the Player class. Should I make an additional merch class? Or has something gone wrong?

Comment: @Velcrode Something's gone wrong. You may need to ask a new question, but for now, edit your current question with all the updated code

Comment: Thanks a load for your help, Haidro. Couldn't've gotten closer to the solution without ye!

Comment: @Velcrode I'm actually not sure about your recent error. It should work fine. Must be something else in the code. Sorry :(. But you're welcome :)

Comment: I'll go over it again. You're awesome!